# Kubernetes wasting resources

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a kubernetes cluster for which a workload with Request : 1000m CPU and Limit 1200m CPU is deployed. Node template is 4-8096 and we never hit the RAM as workloads are more compute intensive.

My issue is as shown in the picture when the Auto-Scaler scaled the workload to 2 PODs, Kubernetes didn't scheduled the additional pod in the same node even though there is plenty of resources available. (2/3.92). Instead it had to schedule it on a new Node. This is a lot of waste and cost insensitive when we scale further up.

Is this normal behavior or what best practices can you recommend to achieve a better resource utilization?

Thanks.
Nowa.

[image: Resource distribiution]

**UPDATE:**

**After applying the autoscaling-profile to optimize-utilization as suggested by the Erhard Czving's answer, the additional pod was scheduled onto the same node. So now as per total requests that's 3/3.92 ~ 76%.**

[image]

Comment: By default kubernetes schedule pods to least idle nodes. I dont think thats resource wasting.

Comment: We start with single node, so why would autoscaler spawn an idle node in the first place, when the existing node can cater more pods?

Comment: Well then maybe your deployment has affinity/anti-affinity rule that pods cant run on same node. Therefore autoscaler had to create second node and deploy pod to there.

Comment: we have node selectors wo this nodepool only schedules this specific workload, but there's no other restrictions. There's a new answer so i'll try that option and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [optimize-utilization](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler#autoscaling_profiles) autoscaling profile.

It should keep the utilization much higher than the default profile, depending on the Kubernetes version used. Around 80% utilization is a good estimate.

Apply to a cluster with gcloud commands:

```
gcloud beta container clusters update example-cluster --autoscaling-profile optimize-utilization
```

Comment: Now that kind of worked, but I had to force scale down the node-pool to 1 to kick start new node/pod scheduling.